# How to use analysis of deviance to test parameters

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, deviance

Radiation is applied and we take a sample of cells. Due to radiation, some of these cells are dicentric. I am modelling the ratio of dicentrics per cell against dose. The experiment is repeated in 2 labs. Each laboratory (Ed or Pittsburgh) has 2 type of cultures: immediate analysis of cells after radiation, or waiting 48 hours after radiation.  Here are my data:

```
Dose Cells Dicentrics Laboratory Culture
0.1 328 2 Edinburgh Immediate
0.2 723 1 Edinburgh Immediate
0.5 513 4 Edinburgh Immediate
1.0 369 4 Edinburgh Immediate
1.5 280 7 Edinburgh Immediate
2.0 361 19 Edinburgh Immediate
3.0 238 26 Edinburgh Immediate
0.1 847 1 Edinburgh Stored
0.2 1404 3 Edinburgh Stored
0.5 492 3 Edinburgh Stored
1.0 489 10 Edinburgh Stored
1.5 533 26 Edinburgh Stored
2.0 1112 98 Edinburgh Stored
3.0 422 74 Edinburgh Stored
0.1 172 1 Pittsburgh Immediate
0.2 345 1 Pittsburgh Immediate
0.5 277 3 Pittsburgh Immediate
1.0 364 8 Pittsburgh Immediate
1.5 235 5 Pittsburgh Immediate
2.0 307 15 Pittsburgh Immediate
3.0 238 20 Pittsburgh Immediate
0.1 585 1 Pittsburgh Stored
0.2 1002 3 Pittsburgh Stored
0.5 472 5 Pittsburgh Stored
1.0 493 14 Pittsburgh Stored
1.5 408 30 Pittsburgh Stored
2.0 690 75 Pittsburgh Stored
3.0 291 46 Pittsburgh Stored
```

**What I want to do:**

1. Compare 2 models
2. Test dependence on location and analysis type

I plotted prediction lines for the data which looks like:

[image]

The choice of quadratic model is: $E(Y)=C(\beta_0+\beta_1 D + \beta_2 D^2)$ where $Y$ is the number of dicentrics, $D$ is dose and $C$ is cells.

**Laboratory Dependence:**
I fit 4 subset models independently, using subsets 1:7,8:14,15:21,22:28. The total deviance of 4 independent models is $D=9.067335$ with $16$ df.

I plotted another 2 more models which ignore dependence on the lab, and only include culture. These correspond to culture=immediate and culture=stored respectively. I found that the deviance is $D=15.3982$ with $22$ df.

Hence the null hypothesis of no dependence on lab is tested by comparing $15.3982-9.067335=6.33$ with $\chi ^2_{22-16}=12.59$. Hence we have insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis, and labs could be independent.

**Why I don't think this is right:**
By looking at the plot, it seems that the lab should be highly significant.
When I do an analysis of deviance on paper, it seems I am comparing the number of parameters and not degrees of freedom. So in this case I should compare it with $\chi^2_1$ since only lab parameter is different in those models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I have no idea what you did.  It doesn't sound right, but it's hard to say.  Here is how I'd analyze your data:

```
d = read.table(text="  Dose Cells Dicentrics Laboratory Culture
                        0.1 328 2 Edinburgh Immediate
                        ...
                        3.0 291 46 Pittsburgh Stored", header=T)
```

The first thing to notice is that these are binomial data.  That is, they are counts of 'successes' out of a known total number of 'trials'.  You need to use a logistic regression model here.  I start with a full model with all interactions (in part because I have no idea what this is), and I include a squared effect of `Dose` (because you seem to want that).

```
m = glm(cbind(Dicentrics, Cells-Dicentrics)~poly(Dose,2)*Culture*Laboratory, 
        d, family=binomial)
summary(m)
# output omitted
```

We can use analysis of deviance tests (i.e., a likelihood ratio test of a nested model) to test the three-way interaction and the need for the squared term:

```
anova(update(m, .~poly(Dose,1)*Culture*Laboratory, d), m, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 1) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory + poly(Dose, 1):Culture + poly(Dose, 1):Laboratory + 
#     Culture:Laboratory + poly(Dose, 1):Culture:Laboratory
# Model 2: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) * Culture * 
#     Laboratory
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
# 1        20     65.812                          
# 2        16      6.457  4   59.355 3.963e-12 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
anova(update(m, .~.-poly(Dose,2):Culture:Laboratory, d), m, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory + poly(Dose, 2):Culture + poly(Dose, 2):Laboratory + 
#     Culture:Laboratory
# Model 2: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) * Culture * 
#     Laboratory
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
# 1        18     6.6571                     
# 2        16     6.4569  2  0.20016   0.9048
```

You seem to be right about the need for a polynomial fit, but there really doesn't seem to be any need for the three-way interaction.

At this point, modeling philosophies diverge: many will drop the interaction, but some advise against it.  I am generally uncomfortable with dropping variables just because they are not significant, but this is sufficiently non-significant that I don't see much problem.  In particular, dropping the interaction can make testing and interpreting the model simpler.

```
m2 = glm(cbind(Dicentrics, Cells-Dicentrics)~(poly(Dose,2)+Culture+Laboratory)^2, 
         d, family=binomial)
summary(m2)
# output omitted
```

This fits a model with three two-way interactions, but not the three-way.  We can conduct subsequent tests of these two-way interactions.

```
anova(update(m2, .~.-poly(Dose,2):Culture, d), m2, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory + poly(Dose, 2):Laboratory + Culture:Laboratory
# Model 2: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ (poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory)^2
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
# 1        20    12.9341                       
# 2        18     6.6571  2    6.277  0.04335 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
anova(update(m2, .~.-poly(Dose,2):Laboratory, d), m2, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory + poly(Dose, 2):Culture + Culture:Laboratory
# Model 2: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ (poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory)^2
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
# 1        20    12.0733                       
# 2        18     6.6571  2   5.4163  0.06666 .
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
anova(update(m2, .~.-Culture:Laboratory, d), m2, test="LRT")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory + poly(Dose, 2):Culture + poly(Dose, 2):Laboratory
# Model 2: cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ (poly(Dose, 2) + Culture + 
#     Laboratory)^2
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
# 1        19     7.5582                     
# 2        18     6.6571  1   0.9011   0.3425
```

Here we see that there seems to be a `Dose` by `Culture` interaction (which I suspect makes scientific sense), no evidence of a `Culture` by `Laboratory` interaction (which also seems plausible), and a `Dose` by `Laboratory` interaction that doesn't quite meet the traditional criterion for 'statistical significance' (I'm not sure whether its existence makes sense).  Although a p-value of $0.34$ might be kind of low, the observed value of the test statistic is $0.9$, which is less than the expected value of a $\chi^2$ random variable on $1$ df.  I am slightly uncomfortable with dropping this, but willing to do so in the name of enhanced simplicity and interpretability.  I would not drop the `Dose` by `Laboratory` interaction, however.  (So the model remains somewhat harder to interpret.)  The existence of the interaction that includes `Laboratory` implies that it is potentially relevant.

Here I fit the final model:

```
m3 = glm(cbind(Dicentrics, Cells-Dicentrics)~poly(Dose,2)*Laboratory+
                                             poly(Dose,2)*Culture, 
         d, family=binomial)
summary(m3)
# Call:
# glm(formula = cbind(Dicentrics, Cells - Dicentrics) ~ poly(Dose, 
#     2) * Laboratory + poly(Dose, 2) * Culture, family = binomial, 
#     data = d)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.1235  -0.3427   0.1043   0.3425   0.9214  
# 
# Coefficients:
#                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)                          -4.2729     0.1682 -25.405   <2e-16 ***
# poly(Dose, 2)1                        6.7074     0.8008   8.376   <2e-16 ***
# poly(Dose, 2)2                       -0.7665     0.6117  -1.253   0.2101    
# LaboratoryPittsburgh                  0.2929     0.1786   1.641   0.1009    
# CultureStored                         0.2206     0.1849   1.193   0.2328    
# poly(Dose, 2)1:LaboratoryPittsburgh  -1.0325     0.8358  -1.235   0.2167    
# poly(Dose, 2)2:LaboratoryPittsburgh  -0.4245     0.5749  -0.738   0.4603    
# poly(Dose, 2)1:CultureStored          2.1885     0.8796   2.488   0.0128 *  
# poly(Dose, 2)2:CultureStored         -1.3988     0.6500  -2.152   0.0314 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 759.2740  on 27  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance:   7.5582  on 19  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 132.86
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

To evaluate and interpret this model, I make a plot of the data with the model's predicted values overlaid.  To get a quick sense of the variability associated with each point (proportion dicentric), I compute the normal approximation of the binomial's standard error and plot that for each point as well.

```
xseq = seq(0,3, by=.1)
prop = with(d, Dicentrics/Cells)
pSE  = with(d, sqrt(prop*(1-prop)/Cells))

pchs = with(d, ifelse(Laboratory=="Edinburgh"&Culture=="Immediate",   1,
               ifelse(Laboratory=="Pittsburgh"&Culture=="Immediate", 16,
               ifelse(Laboratory=="Edinburgh"&Culture=="Stored",      2, 17))))
windows()
  with(d, plot(Dose, Dicentrics/Cells, pch=pchs))
  with(d, arrows(x0=Dose, y0=prop-pSE, y1=prop+pSE, code=3, length=.05, angle=90))
  lines(xseq, lty=1, y=predict(m3, data.frame(Dose       =xseq, 
                                              Laboratory ="Edinburgh",
                                              Culture    ="Immediate" ), type="r"))
  lines(xseq, lty=2, y=predict(m3, data.frame(Dose       =xseq, 
                                              Laboratory ="Pittsburgh",
                                              Culture    ="Immediate" ), type="r"))
  lines(xseq, lty=3, y=predict(m3, data.frame(Dose       =xseq, 
                                              Laboratory ="Edinburgh",
                                              Culture    ="Stored" ), type="r"))
  lines(xseq, lty=4, y=predict(m3, data.frame(Dose       =xseq, 
                                              Laboratory ="Pittsburgh",
                                              Culture    ="Stored" ), type="r"))
  legend("topleft", lty=1:4, pch=c(1,16,2,17),
         legend=c("Edinburgh Immediate", "Pittsburgh Immediate",
                  "Edinburgh Stored", "Pittsburgh Stored"))
```

[image]

From the plot, we can see that the interaction with `Laboratory` is necessitated by different effects at higher doses when the cells were stored.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to play around with this tomorrow